# Перевод страницы js

Tags: javascript, i18n, перевод

Есть лендинг и готовый документ с переводом. Подскажите. где можно посмотреть пример кода такой функции типа getTranslate, которая ищет все элементы с data-атрибутом и указывает text-content.

Comment: И вправду легче написать свою

Answer (score 2):

Писал когда-то простой скрипт для перевода интерфейсов:
Создаешь объект strings с ключами языка (strings.ru, strings en etc.).
Пример объекта:

```
strings.ru = {
'auth.community': 'Сообщество',
'auth.shop': 'Магазин',
'auth.help': 'Поддержка',
'auth.title': 'Авторизация',
}
```

Далее функция, которая принимает язык и ключ строки:

```
function getString(lang, key) {
if (strings[lang].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return strings[lang][key];
} else {
    return key;
}
```

И соответственно функция, которая при открытии страницы собирает все и переводит на нужный язык. В тегах, внутрь которых нужно вставить перевод - добавляем аттрибуты innerString или если нужен плейсхоледр то innerPlaceholder.

```
function translateInterface(language) {
    const stringsPlace = document.querySelectorAll('[innerString]');
    const placeholdersPlace = document.querySelectorAll('[innerPlaceholder]');

    for (const string of stringsPlace) {
        string.innerHTML = getString(language, string.getAttribute('innerString'));
    }

    for (const placeholder of placeholdersPlace) {
        placeholder.setAttribute('placeholder', getString(language, placeholder.getAttribute('innerPlaceholder')));
    }
}
```